# Can you get a single worker for a single die if you can only use one die roll?

Tags: the-castles-of-burgundy

We were playing The Castles of Burgandy.

A player rolled two 5's, and it was late in the phase.  There was a 5 play, by putting a building on a hex, which he did.  But there was no other action he could take with a 5.  He had no worker with which to switch the 5 to a 4 or a 6.  We looked at the rule about abandoning both dice for two workers, but it did not appear clear if one can abandon one die for a single worker.

Is this within the rules: take an action on the result of a single die, and forfeit the action of the other die in return for a single worker?

We house ruled it as 'yes' since it's less frustrating for the players.  We are new to the game and are unsure if that's a good house rule or even a valid one.

Answer (score 10):

### You only need one die to get two workers

From the Castles of Burgundy rules, sourced [here](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules4/The%20castles%20of%20burgundy%20-%20rules.pdf)

> **Action "Take worker tiles"**
> Finally, a player may choose to use any die result to take 2 worker
> tiles from the general supply. In this case, the die result itself is
> meaningless.

The word 'die' is singular, indicating that you only need a single die to take this action.  This is in keeping with every other action in the game - every action takes exactly one die.

So any house rules are unnecessary.

Comment: The key is that taking workers is just a normal action; same as building or trading goods.

Comment: @GendoIkari aaah, we looked at the pictures on the right and were under the impression that you had to use two dice for two workers. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast which pictures? In my copy of the rule book, this sentence is on page 9. There is no picture of dice on this or adjacent pages.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh probably the pictures on the bottom right of the player boards featuring two workers, if I had to guess.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Arcanist Lupus is right; the figure in the lower right hand corner of the standard playing board.